# Fitbit auth for multiple users

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, fitbit

I am developing Client App based on Fitbit API to display fitness parameters (like calories, steps, distance and duration) of multiple users on device like TV (TV being a shared device for multiple users at home).

But Fitbit allows to login and authenticate (OAuth2 based) using default browser for single user at any time.

So my question is:
If I login to default browser and authenticate user1 and then later logout user1 so that I can login user2, then can I still use auth_keys of user1 to get user1 fitness parameters as well as using auth_keys of user2 to get user2 fitness parameters?

Comment: Further to the above query: is it possible to show the list of Fitbit users in browser page so that one of the users can be selected for which authentication can be done? This avoids logging out existing user and then logging in another user so that data can be pulled out for multiple users. Or is this just a wish!!